# Pandas split CSV into multiple CSV's (or DataFrames) by a column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby

I'm very lost with a problem and some help or tips will be appreciated.

The problem: I've a csv file with a column with the possibility of multiple values like:

```
Fruit;Color;The_evil_column
Apple;Red;something1
Apple;Green;something1
Orange;Orange;something1
Orange;Green;something2
Apple;Red;something2
Apple;Red;something3
```

I've loaded the data into a dataframe and i need to split that dataframe into multiple dataframes based on the value of the column "The_evil_column":

```
df1
Fruit;Color;The_evil_column
Apple;Red;something1
Apple;Green;something1
Orange;Orange;something1

df2
Fruit;Color;The_evil_column
Orange;Green;something2
Apple;Red;something2

df3
Fruit;Color;The_evil_column
Apple;Red;something3
```

After reading some posts i'm even more confused and i need some tip about this please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can generate a dictionary of DataFrames:

```
d = {g:x for g,x in df.groupby('The_evil_column')}

In [95]: d.keys()
Out[95]: dict_keys(['something1', 'something2', 'something3'])

In [96]: d['something1']
Out[96]:
    Fruit   Color The_evil_column
0   Apple     Red      something1
1   Apple   Green      something1
2  Orange  Orange      something1
```

or a list of DataFrames:

```
In [103]: l = [x for _,x in df.groupby('The_evil_column')]

In [104]: l[0]
Out[104]:
    Fruit   Color The_evil_column
0   Apple     Red      something1
1   Apple   Green      something1
2  Orange  Orange      something1

In [105]: l[1]
Out[105]:
    Fruit  Color The_evil_column
3  Orange  Green      something2
4   Apple    Red      something2

In [106]: l[2]
Out[106]:
   Fruit Color The_evil_column
5  Apple   Red      something3
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [111]: g = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';').groupby('The_evil_column')

In [112]: g.ngroups   # number of unique values in the `The_evil_column` column
Out[112]: 3

In [113]: g.apply(lambda x: x.to_csv(r'c:\temp\{}.csv'.format(x.name)))
Out[113]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

will produce 3 files:

```
In [115]: glob.glob(r'c:\temp\something*.csv')
Out[115]:
['c:\\temp\\something1.csv',
 'c:\\temp\\something2.csv',
 'c:\\temp\\something3.csv']
```

Comment: Loved that dict generation ( very nice to know !) but what i wanted was the list what worked perfectly, now ill try to make the funtion to store the data with to_csv after counting how many evil things has the evil column. Thank you so much !!

Comment: @EliasCortAguelo, glad i could help. What is your end-goal? To split one CSV by `The_evil_column` colum?

Comment: Yes thats the idea i've a var named counter with value of 0 and a for loop like """for result in range(len(d)): counter += 1 print l[counter]""", it returns the 3 dataframes but gives a final error with "IndexError: list index out of range""".

Comment: @EliasCortAguelo, please see update section - if i understand correctly it should do what you want...

Comment: Wow incredible, thank you !! That was exactly what i needed, so nice really. Very very thank you MaxU, learned a lot with your help !!

Comment: Another way to have a list of dataframe is using `l = list(df.groupby('The_evil_column'))` to access to the `i` `df` write `l[i][1]`

Comment: @user32185, this will produce a list of __tuples__, where first element is a group name and a second one - a dataframe

Comment: that's why to access the access the `df` is via `l[i][1]` ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can just filter the frame by the value of the column:

```
frame=pd.read_csv('file.csv',delimiter=';')
frame['The_evil_column']=='something1'
```

this returns:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: The_evil_column, dtype: bool
```

Therefore you access these columns:

```
frame1 = frame[frame['The_evil_column']=='something1']
```

Later you can drop the column:

```
frame1 = frame1.drop('The_evil_column', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler but less efficient way is:

```
data = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

out = []

for evil_element in list(set(list(data['The_evil_column']))):
    out.append(data[data['The_evil_column']==evil_element])
```

`out` will have list of all data dataframes.