# How to extract and save in .csv chunks of data from a large .csv file iteratively using Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and I attempt to read a large .csv file (with hundreds of thousands or possibly few millions of rows; and about 15.000 columns) using pandas.

What I thought I could do is to create and save each chunk in a new .csv file, iteratively across all chunks. I am currently using a lap top with relatively limited memory (of about 4 Gb, in the process of upgrading it) but I was wondering whether I could do this without changing my set up now. Alternatively, I could transfer this process in a pc with large RAM and attempt larger chunks, but I wanted to get this in place even for shorter row chunks.

I have seen that I can process quickly chunks of data (e.g. 10.000 rows and all columns), using the code below. But due to me being a Python beginner, I have only managed to order the first chunk. I would like to loop iteratively across chunks and save them.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

print(os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))

chunksize = 10000

data = pd.read_csv('ukb35190.csv', chunksize=chunksize)

df = data.get_chunk(chunksize)

print(df)

export_csv1 = df.to_csv (r'/home/user/PycharmProjects/PROJECT/export_csv_1.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a 6 GB csv file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007017/pandas-split-csv-into-multiple-csvs-or-dataframes-by-a-column)

Comment: Are you doing any processing in pandas or are you just using it for splitting?  Does the original file have headers?

Comment: Thank you Steven. I am just using it for splitting here (in this script). The original file has headers which I found a way to attach in every new .csv file. I still can't figure out a way to save my large .csv file into smaller new .csv files though. Most of the previous questions address how to process but not how to save every step, into a new .csv. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not doing any processing on data then you dont have to even store it in any variable.You can do it directly. PFA code below.Hope this would help u.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

chunksize = 10000
batch=1

for chunk in pd.read_csv(r'ukb35190.csv',chunksize=chunk_size):
  chunk.to_csv(r'ukb35190.csv'+str(batch_no)+'.csv',index=False)
  batch_no+=1
```