# Split one CSV file into multiple new CSV files based on the value of one column

Tags: python, csv

I want to split one big CSV file into multiple new CSV files.

There is a column `SYMBOL` I want the new CSV files on that name.
There are around 200 symbols.

List of columns in the big CSV file are:

- INSTRUMENT
- SYMBOL
- EXPIRY_DT
- STRIKE_PR
- OPTION_TYP
- OPEN
- HIGH
- LOW
- CLOSE
- SETTLE_PR
- CONTRACTS
- VAL_INLAKH
- OPEN_INT
- CHG_IN_OI
- TIMESTAMP

#### Code

I have a code where I can do for one single symbol.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
zip_file_list=glob.glob('*.zip')
symbol='ACC'
DATE=[]
OPEN=[]
HIGH=[]
LOW=[]
CLOSE=[]
OI=[]
VOLUME=[]
COI=[]
for i in range (0,len(zip_file_list)):
    df=pd.read_csv(zip_file_list[i])
    Open=df['OPEN'][(df.INSTRUMENT=='FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL==symbol)].iloc[0]
    High=df['HIGH'][(df.INSTRUMENT=='FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL==symbol)].iloc[0]
    Low=df['LOW'][(df.INSTRUMENT=='FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL==symbol)].iloc[0]
    Close=df['CLOSE'][(df.INSTRUMENT=='FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL==symbol)].iloc[0]
    Volume=df['CONTRACTS'][(df.INSTRUMENT=='FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL==symbol)].iloc[0]
    oi=df['OPEN_INT'][(df.INSTRUMENT=='FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL==symbol)].sum()
    coi = df['CHG_IN_OI'][(df.INSTRUMENT == 'FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL == symbol)].sum()
    date=df['TIMESTAMP'].iloc[0]
    DATE.append(date)
    OPEN.append(Open)
    HIGH.append(High)
    LOW.append(Low)
    CLOSE.append(Close)
    VOLUME.append(Volume)
    OI.append(oi)
    COI.append(coi)
data={'DATE':DATE,'OPEN':OPEN,'HIGH':HIGH,'LOW':LOW,'CLOSE':CLOSE,'VOLUME':VOLUME,'OI':OI,'COI':COI}
ndf=pd.DataFrame(data)
ndf.to_csv(symbol+'.csv',index=False)
```

#### Issue

I don't know how to loop through all symbols in that file and create a new file for each distinct symbol.

Then I wish to append daily data to that newly created files.

When I run the code and I have the daily data of 10 days, then I get a file with 10 days data appended for the single symbol mentioned.

But I want that to happen to all the symbols in the big data file.
I don't know how to loop through the symbol list and all the file in the dict to append data.

Comment: Does your solution strictly require [tag:pandas]? Then you should add this tag to your question.

Comment: It seems that pandas makes the task more difficult.
pandas is a library dedicated to data science here you don't want to analyze data but process "raw" data, implement a custom logic and do a lot of I/O operations. Pure python is likely to be a more simple and more efficient answer.

Comment: If the ZIP file extraction is not the issue here, please research for already existing answers using search `[csv] [python] split CSV into multiple by column` and find e.g. [Pandas split CSV into multiple CSV's (or DataFrames) by a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007017/pandas-split-csv-into-multiple-csvs-or-dataframes-by-a-column)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas split CSV into multiple CSV's (or DataFrames) by a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007017/pandas-split-csv-into-multiple-csvs-or-dataframes-by-a-column)

Answer (score 1):

First, make a unique list of all the symbols, and iterate through the list using the variable in the code you already have + something else to handle the storage of the data... something like this. Just make sure the data is not that big that can cause a MemoryError reading all of the files from the zip.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path


def store_data(filename, dataframe):
    # Check if file exists to append the data
    data_file = Path(filename)
    if data_file.is_file():
        dataframe.to_csv(filename, index=False, mode='a', header=False)
    else:
        dataframe.to_csv(filename, index=False)


def extract_symbol_data(dataframes, symbol):
    DATE = []
    OPEN = []
    HIGH = []
    LOW = []
    CLOSE = []
    OI = []
    VOLUME = []
    COI = []

    for df in dataframes:
        Open = df['OPEN'][(df.INSTRUMENT == 'FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL == symbol)].iloc[0]
        High = df['HIGH'][(df.INSTRUMENT == 'FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL == symbol)].iloc[0]
        Low = df['LOW'][(df.INSTRUMENT == 'FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL == symbol)].iloc[0]
        Close = df['CLOSE'][(df.INSTRUMENT == 'FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL == symbol)].iloc[0]
        Volume = df['CONTRACTS'][(df.INSTRUMENT == 'FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL == symbol)].iloc[0]
        oi = df['OPEN_INT'][(df.INSTRUMENT == 'FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL == symbol)].sum()
        coi = df['CHG_IN_OI'][(df.INSTRUMENT == 'FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL == symbol)].sum()
        date = df['TIMESTAMP'].iloc[0]

        DATE.append(date)
        OPEN.append(Open)
        HIGH.append(High)
        LOW.append(Low)
        CLOSE.append(Close)
        VOLUME.append(Volume)
        OI.append(oi)
        COI.append(coi)

    data = {'DATE': DATE, 'OPEN': OPEN, 'HIGH': HIGH, 'LOW': LOW, 'CLOSE': CLOSE, 'VOLUME': VOLUME, 'OI': OI, 'COI': COI}
    ndf = pd.DataFrame(data)
    store_data(filename=symbol + '.csv', dataframe=ndf)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    zip_file_list = glob.glob('*.zip')

    # List of all the needed data files
    dataframes = [
        pd.read_csv(zip_file_list[i])
        for i in range(len(zip_file_list))
    ]

    symbols = set()
    # Set of all exising symbols in the data
    for df in dataframes:
        for s in df['SYMBOL'].unique():
            symbols.add(s)

    for symbol in symbols:
        extract_symbol_data(dataframes, symbol)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. when running the code it shows error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add' in line 62

Comment: 's  sir can you plz help

Comment: Check it again, I edited that line, you only have to replace it for a set instead of a dictionary

Comment: getting following error now IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds line 65

Comment: also it says this line 26, in extract_symbol_data
    Open = df['OPEN'][(df.INSTRUMENT == 'FUTSTK') & (df.SYMBOL == symbol)].iloc[0]

Comment: if you need any more details plz let me know to understand the issue

Comment: is it memory issue?

Comment: when i put only one file in the folder the code did make 147 new excel files. but there are 199 symbols in the big data file so it should make 199 new files

Comment: when i rerun the code 7 8 times i got 196 new files.

Comment: when i opened few random files few files data was appended and some file data was not appended @Fidel Lopez

Comment: when i print len(symbols) it is showing 198 which is right

Comment: i was trying something and i found when i use zip it can process 45 files and when i use csv file which is inside the zip it process 90 to 95 files.

Comment: till now it has made 193 new files which is one less from the correct number. from that i came to know it does not go in order.it takes random symbols from the list and checks if file it there or no , and if not it makes it.

Comment: but the code you have written is beautiful. :)

Comment: https://archives.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2022/NOV/fo11NOV2022bhav.csv.zip  this is the data file which i am working on. have to sort INSTRUMENT == 'FUTSTK' ,

Comment: ok so now i commented out all the df[] except df open [] i dint get any error  and got all the file properly .  then i found iloc was make the code bad. so i searched what els i can use. then i tried .values[0:1] and the code worked fine , but in excel  file i am getting this { ]  ['04-NOV-2022'] [3241.75] [3289.] [3214.45] [3241.5] [1573] 1493000 99500 how do i get rid of [ ]